# Dynamic click event for buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

I have a button which calls a function via data-bind and generates a new button.

```
self.submitNewPopUp = function(data, event) {
    var butnId = event.srcElement.form.id.replace('style-', '');
    var styleButton = $('<input/>').attr({type: 'button', value: data.styleData, id: butnId});
    styleButton.onclick = function() {
        alert("blabla");
    };
    $("#showButtons").append(styleButton);
    $('#' + event.srcElement.form.id).hide();

};
```

But the new button has no click event. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd assign a click event listener to an ancestor of the button using [jQuery's `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). For instance, if your markup was:

```html
<div id="showButtons">
    <input type="button" />
</div>
```

You'd use:

```javascript
$('#showButtons').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

`styleButton` button is a jQuery object, not a dom element so it does not have a `onclick` property. You need to use the [click(function(){})](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event registration method to register the event handler

```
styleButton.click(function() {
    alert("blabla");
});
```

Comment: Looks like the anwser

Answer (score 1):

Use [jquery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the dynamic created elements

```
$("#div").on("click", "button", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: OP is trying to set handler after element is created. But using delegation would be a solution too